# How to smoothly scroll to a position and make it appear at beginning in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have tried `RecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(int position)`, but it's not what I want. It scrolls to a position so that the child get into the viewport; it can either appear at the beginning or the end. Moreover, if the view is already in the viewport, it won't do anything!

What I need to do is to scroll to a position and make it appear at very beginning of RecyclerView so as to arouse user's attention. How can I do with it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(Position); to display the list item at top. However it will go to the specified position very quickly without any scrolling effect.

Comment: I know this. Of course I want the scrolling effect.